# How to borrow ctx in a module chain

Tags: rust

I have this **entrypoint** where `ctx` is passed by a parent:

```rust
pub mod instructions;

#[program]
pub mod solana_anchor_coinflip {
    use super::*;

    pub fn flip(ctx: Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::play::play(ctx, data)
    }
}
```

Then, `instructions/play.rs` has this:

```rust
pub fn play(ctx: Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> {
    ctx.accounts.game.flip(ctx, data) // <== cannot move out of `ctx` because it is borrowed
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Play<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
}
```

and `ctx` is finally passed to `game.rs`:

```rust
impl Game {
    pub fn flip(&mut self, ctx: Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> {
        self.charge_fee(ctx);

        match data.heads_or_tails {
            true => self.play_heads(ctx), // <== use of moved value: `ctx`
            false => self.play_tails(ctx),
        }
    }

    fn charge_fee(&self, ctx: Context<Play>) -> Result<()> {
        let player = &ctx.accounts.player;

        // ...

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

How to correctly borrow `ctx` from `lib.rs > play.rs > game.rs`?

Comment: Currently you're _moving_ `ctx` into your functions, just _borrow_ it instead, e.g.: `pub fn flip(&mut self, ctx: &Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> { … }`

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you are not borrowing `ctx`, you're just moving it. See the [relevant documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) to understand the differences, alongside with [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow.html) to illustrate that.

If you read through that, you will understand why you just need to change the signature of your functions:

```rust
// in instructions/play.rs
pub fn play(ctx: &Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> { // <-- takes a `&Context<Play>`
  ctx.accounts.game.flip(ctx, data) // and passes the borrow
}

// game.rs
impl Game {
  pub fn flip(&mut self, ctx: &Context<Play>, data: FlipArgs) -> Result<()> { // <-- takes a &Context<Play>
    self.charge_fee(ctx); // <-- here you pass the borrow
                          // also, unused `Result`, which is _bad_
    if data.heads_or_tails { // an `if` statement is a `match` over a `bool`
      self.play_heads(ctx) // <-- here you pass the borrow too, which is fine, because `&T: Copy`
    } else {
      self.play_tails(ctx) // <-- same as above
    }
  }
  fn charge_fee(&self, ctx: &Context<Play>) -> Result<()> { // <-- takes a `&Context<Play>`
    let player = &ctx.accounts.player;
    // ...
    Ok(())
  }
}
```

However, despite this patch, there is a chance that you need to refactor your code anyways after understanding borrow, for multiple motives:

1. Given the context of your question, it's impossible to tell if `play` should take borrow to a `Context<Play>`, or an owned value, because both could work (in the second case, you would have to pass a borrow to the method call, ie `ctx.accounts.game.flip(&ctx, data)`.
2. You seem to pass `data` as an owned value all along, just like you do with `ctx`, but since it was a mistake with `ctx`, it might be for `data` too (and for many other parts of your code).
3. I'm not sure whether the current version will compile anyways do the `flip` requiring `&mut self`, that is, it needs a mutable borrow to `ctx.accounts.game` in the `play` function. However, that would also require a mutable borrow of `ctx` (unless [it doesn't](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get), but that's a bit too advanced: learn about borrows before learning about interior mutability) for the duration of the call, which would invalidate any borrow to be passed as an argument.

As an advice, I would suggest you to wrap your head around Rust's core concepts (which can be efficiently done by reading the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)) **before** designing the architecture of a complex application, because Rust has some very peculiar patterns, even if you are used other programming languages. Otherwise, you will keep fighting against the compiler trying to adapt the code you had in mind when you still did not fully understand the borrowing and ownership in Rust to something that works.